# Is this possible in JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, deserialization

I am currently working with json.net ! I know how to deserialize json data and how to map with our class. Now I am eager about some queries !

Suppose my jsonstrings is

```
"attributes":{
            "color":"Brown",
            "condition":"Used",
            "currency":"USD",
            "price":"10500",
            "price_display":"$10,500",
         }
```

and my attribute class ( *in which i want to deserialize above string*) is

```
Public class Attribute
{
        public string name{ get; set; }
        public string value{ get; set; }
}
```

Now I am using following code for deserialization.!

```
 JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 <classname> p = ser.Deserialize<classname>(jsonString);
```

And Obviously this code is not going to work for above jsonstring at all.

Now How can I bind these name value pair in one class ?? Is this possible ?

**In future, attributes may b more than 10 but format will be same as name value pair**

Comment: You can probably use the `dynamic` keyword to create a dictionary of dictionaries, eg dictionary<dynamic, object>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I'm sorry, but somehow I interpreted your question as if you wanted to **serialize**, and not **deserialize** (but I'll keep the original below anyway, as I think it's good knowledge :)).

Try to deserialize your JSON string to `Dictionary<string,string>` instead of your `Attribute`. I have a hunch it might work. Then, you can adjust the rest of your code to use that dictionary or you can convert to collection of your `Attribute` instances.

---

The original answer (related to **serializing**, which was the opposite of what you asked for) below.

I don't think so, but if the intention is to use it on the client this way:

```
attributes["color"] // returns Brown
attributes["price"] // returns 10500
```

... then what you're after is called "associative array", as it's equivalent to this:

```
attributes.color
attributes.price
```

... as it's not really an array, but it's an object (javascript provides these two ways to reference object properties; e.g. `window.onload` is the same as `window["onload"]`)...

... and you can achieve this with the JavaScriptSerializer if you serialize `Dictionary<string,string>` to JSON string (in other words, change your `Attribute` class to `KeyValuePair<string,string>`, or otherwise create such dictionary differently.