# C# generic method returning different object instances

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, types

I want do do something like this :

```
class A  {
   public int attribute1;
}

class B {
   public string attribute2;
}

class C {
   public static List<T> get<T>(Dictionary properties){
       //Here is a loop to create
       //new instances of T and setting attributes
   }
}

//I want something like this
Dictionary<string, obj> aProperties = new Dictionary<string, obj>();
aProperties.Add("attribute1", 5);

Dictionary<string, obj> bProperties = new Dictionary<string, obj>();
bProperties.Add("attribute2", "asdf");

List<A> listA = C.get<A>(aProperties); // new Instance of A with attribute1 = 5

List<B> listB = C.get<B>(bProperties); // new Instance of B with attribute2 = "asdf"
```

Can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried doing it? Have you thought about how `Get<T>` is supposed to map between the dictionary and your objects?

Comment: The T is for creating a new instance of the object within the method and the dictionary is for assigning properties. I thought it that way maybe I'm wrong because I don't know the correct way to do it.

Comment: @AntonioPapa If you follow up the answer I provided in the "Marked as duplicate of" you should be able to get to the solution easily..

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer thank you maybe that is the answer :)

Comment: @AntonioPapa Absolutely :D I answered the same question with simpler code here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210428/how-to-convert-class-into-dictionarystring-string/9210493#9210493

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer Thank you again :)

Comment: @AntonioPapa No problem :)