# Dynamic property in Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic

I have the following Linq expression:

```
var itemToUpdate = ItemsUpdated.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == itemId);
```

I need to adapt it so that x.Id is a dynamically defined property, for example:

```
var itemToUpdate = ItemsUpdated.FirstOrDefault(x => x["Id"] == itemId);
```

I have tried the following already which I thought would be enough:

```
var itemToUpdate = ItemsUpdated.FirstOrDefault(x => (int)x.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(x) == itemId);
```

This runs without any errors, but any code after this statement does not execute therefore I assume something goes wrong with the expression above.

Comment: Which types could ’x["Id"]’ theoretically be?

Comment: @JimG. It is only ever an Integer

Comment: In order to make this work, x would either have to be a dictionary, or a class instance having a defined indexer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get property value from C# dynamic object by string (reflection?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8631546/get-property-value-from-c-sharp-dynamic-object-by-string-reflection)

Comment: @Jim G.  It doesn't unfortunately, I've already tried reflection but reflection only seems to work when I want to select, not when I use the property together with "==" comparison operator

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66099661/109941

Comment: @Jim G.  Perhaps but I want to avoid deserializing and serializing seems like overkill, but perhaps I need to rethink this and find an alternative to implementing a dynamic property

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm interested in the possibility of using a Dictionary, could you show me how?

Comment: There are several ways to accomplish some variation of what you're trying to do.  It would be useful if we had more context.  What problem are you trying to solve?  See https://xyproblem.info.